# search an array in sqlite table

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

i have one table like this:

```
      database.execSQL("CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food_table (food_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , food_name CHAR, food_raw CHAR)");
```

and i have an String array like this:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> rawsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

now i want to search in my table and if all of raw of food were in rawsNames return the food_name .

i do this :

```
String raws = AdapterNotes.rawsNames.toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", "");
Cursor cursor = G.database.rawQuery("select * from food_table WHERE food_raw LIKE '%" + raws + "%' ", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("food_name"));
```

But when the food's raw is changed it doesn't work.

please help me.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on here. Can you elaborate on exactly what is changing, and how it prevents the functionality from working?

Comment: Is the SQL database part of the problem? If no, then maybe you can post a compilable and standalone piece of code using string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `food_table` contains the fields:

`food_id` : unique id assigned to a food item
`food_name` : name of the food item
`food_raw` : ingredients separated by `,`

Now, since it is possible that the ingredients be the *same*, but its order be **different** from that stored in the database, a simple `WHERE LIKE %"a, b, c"%` won't work as `b, a, c` are also valid ingredients for the same food (just the order is different).

Hence, you need to match each *individual* ingredient instead of all the ingredients as a whole:

```
String req = "";
for(String rawName : rawNames)
  req += " food_raw LIKE %"+rawName+"% AND";
if(req.length() > 4)
  req = req.substring(0, req.length()-4); // to remove last " AND"
String query = "SELECT * FROM food_table WHERE "+req;
```

Using `query` you should be able to obtain the food name, regardless of item order.