# sqlite rawQuery where in clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

how to execute below query

```
select * from regions where field1 in('word1', 'word2')
```

with sqlite rawQuery method?

I tried below code:

```
String[] myArray = new String[]{"word1","word2"};
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select * from regions where field1 in(?)", myArray );
```

but error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at
>   index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1
>   parameters.

Comment: create a comma separated string and pass it to IN

Comment: check out, possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397280/search-an-array-in-sqlite-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 2 parameters to `rawQuery()`: `"word1"` and `"word2"` but the sql statement contains only 1 placeholder `?`.
Change it to:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select * from regions where field1 in(?, ?)", myArray );
```

Edit.
If you want to pass an unknown number of arguments then you will have to construct the comma delimited argument inside `in` and use only the 1st argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
String[] myArray = new String[]{"word1","word2"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("'");
for (String word : myArray) {
    sb.append(word.replace("'", "''")).append("','");
}
if (sb.length() > 1) {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
}
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select * from regions where field1 in (" + sb.toString() + ")", null);
```

This is not a safe solution and you must prepare correctly the items of the array so they don't include say single quotes (this is why I use `replace()`).

Comment: myArray  has unknown number of elements

Comment: You can't pass it like that. Every item of the array must have a corresponding placeholder. See my edited answer.

Comment: Pass the words is strongly discouraged. It is enough to build the list of placeholders.

Comment: thanks. it has a simple problem, string builder is producing something like this: "'word1',word2'". it needs a single comma before second element.

Answer (score 1):

You binded 2 parameters but your query has only a placeholder.
If you don't know the number at priori, you can do something like this:

```
String inContent = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(myArray.length-1, "?,")).concat("?");
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select * from regions where field1 in(" + inContent + ")", myArray );
```

You are simply writing a query with array.length placeholders separated by a coma. Remember to import java.util.*. in order to use Collections. This method is safe because you don't pass user strings in query.

If you use java11, you could use String::repeat method.

Comment: Yes, I wrote you a comment with the reason but I don't think that my answer is the best place to argue about this.

Comment: I wrote a comment where I explain that, so if you don't agree, just reply to the comment.

Comment: Yes, I read but write "this is not a safe solution" doesn't make a good solution in my opinion so that's why I undervoted, you can agree or not, but this is my opinion.

Comment: Your 1st solution use `String.join()` which requires API level 26. Didn't you even try it?

Comment: What part of "the point is 'use this approach' and not 'use this code' isn't clear?